# JOIN a single, most recent row

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

We have this query that is running:

```sql
SELECT concat_ws(' ', z.ticker,
       CASE
         WHEN a.date_approved IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR(a.date_approved,'YYMMDD')
         WHEN z.date_recommended IS NULL THEN '000000'
         ELSE TO_CHAR(z.date_recommended,'YYMMDD')
       END,
        CASE
          WHEN s.ticker IS NOT NULL THEN 6
          WHEN a.approved_recommendation IS NOT NULL THEN approved_recommendation
          ELSE current_recommendation
        END,
        REPLACE(CASE
                  WHEN comments IS NULL THEN 'N/C'
                  ELSE comments
                END,' ','_'))
FROM recommendations z
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ticker FROM scr_tickers) s
       ON z.ticker = s.ticker
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ticker, date_approved, approved_recommendation
           FROM approved_recommendations) a
       ON z.ticker = a.ticker
WHERE z.ticker NOT LIKE 'T.%'
  AND z.ticker NOT LIKE 'V.%'
ORDER BY z.ticker;
```

Now, they want to add another data item after the `comments`, which is to retrieve the most recent recommendation value from the `recommendations_history` table, where the recommendation value `<>current_recommendation`.

In order to do that, I can do a `join`, use `ROW_NUMBER` with an `ORDER BY` and choose the first row. Is that the best way to achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You can also use the `order by` you suggested and a [`limit 1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html) - does the same in way less code and possibly optimizes better. Instead of `CASE WHEN comments IS NULL THEN 'N/C' ELSE comments END` you can [`COALESCE(comments,'N/C')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

Comment: Why the subqueries? There is no need for, it's just extra noise and space for bugs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, I introduced a `LEFT JOIN` to incorporate the most recent recommendation from the `recommendations_history` table that differs from the current recommendation in the recommendations table. This is achieved by joining a subquery that employs the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, partitioned by ticker and ordered by the recommendation date in descending order.

```
SELECT concat_ws(' ', 
                 z.ticker,
                 CASE
                   WHEN a.date_approved IS NOT NULL THEN TO_CHAR(a.date_approved,'YYMMDD')
                   WHEN z.date_recommended IS NULL THEN '000000'
                   ELSE TO_CHAR(z.date_recommended,'YYMMDD')
                 END,
                 CASE
                   WHEN s.ticker IS NOT NULL THEN 6
                   WHEN a.approved_recommendation IS NOT NULL THEN a.approved_recommendation
                   ELSE z.current_recommendation
                 END,
                 REPLACE(CASE
                             WHEN z.comments IS NULL THEN 'N/C'
                             ELSE z.comments
                           END, ' ', '_'),
                 COALESCE(rh.recommendation, 'No Recent Recommendation')
               )
FROM recommendations z
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ticker FROM scr_tickers) s ON z.ticker = s.ticker
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ticker, date_approved, approved_recommendation
           FROM approved_recommendations) a ON z.ticker = a.ticker
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ticker, recommendation, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY recommendation_date DESC) AS rn
           FROM recommendations_history
           WHERE recommendation <> (SELECT current_recommendation FROM recommendations WHERE ticker = recommendations_history.ticker)
          ) rh ON z.ticker = rh.ticker AND rh.rn = 1
WHERE z.ticker NOT LIKE 'T.%'
  AND z.ticker NOT LIKE 'V.%'
ORDER BY z.ticker;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT concat_ws(' ', 
     z.ticker,
     COALESCE(TO_CHAR(a.date_approved,   'YYMMDD'),
              TO_CHAR(z.date_recommended,'YYMMDD'),
              '000000'),
     CASE WHEN s.ticker IS NOT NULL THEN 6
          ELSE COALESCE(a.approved_recommendation, current_recommendation)
     END,
     REPLACE(COALESCE(comments,'N/C'),' ','_'),
     h.recommendation_value)
FROM recommendations z
LEFT JOIN scr_tickers s              USING (ticker)
LEFT JOIN approved_recommendations a USING (ticker)
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT rh.ticker, rh.recommendation_value
        FROM recommendations_history rh
        WHERE z.current_recommendation<>rh.recommendation_value
        ORDER BY date_recommended DESC LIMIT 1) h
    USING (ticker)
WHERE z.ticker NOT LIKE ALL(ARRAY['T.%','V.%'])
ORDER BY z.ticker;
```

0. Use an `order by` the way you planned, but combine it with a simple [`limit 1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html).
1. `case when x is null then y else x end` translates to [`coalesce(x,y)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)
2. [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) function returns `null` if it gets `null` on input, so you can safely list it in `coalesce()` argument list.
3. [`join using`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.4.3.1.1) saves you equations and coalescing same-name columns
4. As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77869225/join-a-single-most-recent-row#comment137279437_77869225) by [@Frank Heikens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens), you can `join` directly. You're not saving/speeding up anything by specifying a shorter list of columns in a subquery - the [planner/optimizer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/planner-optimizer.html) sees which ones are required and only targets those, [regardless of whether you do that or not](https://dbfiddle.uk/gZ7PNcjY).
5. You can use

   - [`a NOT LIKE ALL(ARRAY[e1,e2])`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-ALL) or
   - [`a NOT LIKE ALL(VALUES(e1),(e2))`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ALL)
   - instead of `a NOT LIKE e1 AND a NOT LIKE e2`

   which gives you a single list to maintain and lets you move it to a table somewhere and retrieve with a subquery, instead of hardcoding these exclusions, each as a separate `and...not like`.

[Demo at db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/uJ6-1eMs)

Answer (score 0):

Requirements need to be precise in programming matters.
Your criteria is **ambiguous** in three major ways:

> retrieve the most recent recommendation value from the
> `recommendations_history` table, where the recommendation value
> `<>current_recommendation`.

1. This can be translated in two meaningfully different ways:

   - 1a. *Get the most recent recommendation, then check whether it's different.*
   - 1b. *Get the most recent recommendation that is also different.*
2. You make it sound like *any* row from `recommendations_history` would be a candidate, while I am pretty sure you'll only want to consider *related* rows - in which case you'd need to define the relation. I'll **assume** another match on the column `ticker`?
3. This addition will produce surprising results if any of (`recommendation`, `current_recommendation`, `date_recommended`) can be null. You'd need to rule out null values or disclose `CREATE TABLE` statements and define desired behavior. I'll **assume** all involved columns are `NOT NULL`.

I would implement variant **1a** with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT concat_ws(' '
         , r.ticker
         , COALESCE(to_char(COALESCE(a.date_approved, z.date_recommended),'YYMMDD'), '000000')
         , CASE WHEN s.ticker IS NOT NULL THEN 6 ELSE COALESCE(a.approved_recommendation, r.current_recommendation) END
         , COALESCE(translate(r.comments, ' ', '_') 'N/C')
         , (SELECT h.recommendation
            FROM   recommendations_history h
            WHERE  h.ticker = r.ticker
            AND    h.recommendation <> r.current_recommendation  --!?
            ORDER  BY h.date_recommended DESC
            LIMIT  1)
         ) AS my_field_name
FROM   recommendations r
LEFT   JOIN scr_tickers s USING (ticker)
LEFT   JOIN approved_recommendations a USING (ticker)
WHERE  r.ticker !~ '^[TV]\.'
ORDER  BY r.ticker;
```

For variant **1b** we have to check *after* finding the latest row, so use a `LATERAL` subquery:

```
SELECT concat_ws(' '
         , r.ticker
         , COALESCE(to_char(COALESCE(a.date_approved, z.date_recommended),'YYMMDD'), '000000')
         , CASE WHEN s.ticker IS NOT NULL THEN 6 ELSE COALESCE(a.approved_recommendation, r.current_recommendation) END
         , COALESCE(translate(r.comments, ' ', '_') 'N/C')
         , h.recommendation
         ) AS my_field_name
FROM   recommendations r
LEFT   JOIN scr_tickers s USING (ticker)
LEFT   JOIN approved_recommendations a USING (ticker)
LEFT   JOIN LATERAL (  -- must be LATERAL!
   SELECT h.recommendation
   FROM   recommendations_history h
   WHERE  h.ticker = r.ticker
   ORDER  BY h.date_recommended DESC
   LIMIT  1
   ) h ON h.recommendation <> r.current_recommendation
WHERE  r.ticker !~ '^[TV]\.'
ORDER  BY r.ticker;
```

See:

- [What is the difference between a LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28550679/what-is-the-difference-between-a-lateral-join-and-a-subquery-in-postgresql/28557803#28557803)

[`concat_ws()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.5.1.1.1) ignores null values, so we don't have to special-case null additions.

`WHERE  r.ticker !~ '^[TV]\.'` (optionally) wraps up your two `LIKE` predicates.

Plus, what [Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/users/271959/frank-heikens) already commented about pointless subqueries, and what [Zegarek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5298879/zegarek) already provided concerning [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL).

Comment: 1A is a good version.   One thing Oracle keeps missing, an equivalent of the LIMIT clause.

Comment: Oracle supports the equivalent SQL standard syntax `FETCH FIRST N ROWS ONLY` since version 12c. (Like Postgres also does.) I wonder why you accepted the least optimized answer.